# where am i going wrong in my nextPerson function,as the code is breaking once all the persons are lopped over

Tags: reactjs

the function ***nextPerson*** has some issue i am not able to figure out..i want to loop over all the people in people array , it is looping through the people but the code is breaking once it loops over every person. **Also**,the first console log of **next** is giving 0.shouldnt it be 1? if it has to do something with the way event occcurs?
please help

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import people from "./data";
import { FaChevronLeft, FaChevronRight, FaQuoteRight } from "react-icons/fa";

const Review = () => {
  const [next, setNext] = useState(0);
  const { id, name, job, image, text } = people[next];
  const nextPerson = () => {
    console.log(people.length);
    if (next < people.length) {
      setNext(next + 1);
      console.log(next);//after 1st click its outputting 0 ,isnt it should be 1?
    } else {
      setNext(0);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="review container">
        <div className="img-container">
          <img src={image} alt="" className="person-img" />;
          <div className="quote-icon">
            <FaQuoteRight />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h4>{name}</h4>
        <p className="job">{job}</p>
        <p className="info">{text}</p>
        <button className="prev-btn">
          <FaChevronLeft />
        </button>
        <button className="next-btn" onClick={nextPerson}>
          <FaChevronRight />
        </button>
        <div>
          <button className="random-btn">Surprise Me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Review;
```

Comment: ok changing the condition from if (next < people.length) to  if (next < people.length -1) is making the code work. but i dont know why?  shouldnt  (next <people.length-1) restrict the looping to one element less than the total number of array elements

Comment: It is because when the length is 1, you access that object with an index of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const nextPerson = () => {
  console.log(people.length);
  if (next < people.length) {
    setNext(next + 1);
    console.log(next);
  } else {
    setNext(0);
  }
};
```

It is normal for `console.log(next);` to output 0 because `setState` is async.

As for the loop, consider the `people` array of length 10, when `next` is 9, `next < people.length` is still true, so `next` is then being set to `10`. Now you are trying to access `people[10]`, which is obviously not gonna work.

Comment: oh Thank you so much, it would have taken me real long to figure out the async thing, a  lil hike and fresh prespective did clear out the array length confusion..